# C : write() fails while writing to a RAW disk after specific size limit reached

Tags: c, linux, unix, filesystems, disk

I am using a C program `open(), close(), read(), write()` technique to copy a large file to RAW disk. The disk size is 20 GB and the file size is 17 GB but, every time  after around writing 945 MB `write()` throws `No space left on device` error.

I have run `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` and returns 20.5 GB and `du /dev/sdb` says `945126569`

Then I tried, `cat mylargefile > /dev/sdb` it too throws same `No space left on device` error and then I do `cat /dev/sdb > /tmp/sdb.img` it completes normally. Then I do `ls -ld /tmp/sdb.img` it responds `945126569`

I can use the same disk to create `ext4` file system and format it without any issues, so disk error is improbable. (I guess ...)

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64 OS with latest GCC to build my program.

Can anyone suggest where am I going wrong or what needs to be done to avoid this?

Comment: `du /dev/sdb` should say **0**.

Comment: Remember that disk-sizes are usually in multiples of 1000, while file-sizes are in multiples of 1024. Have you checked for that discrepancy?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude pebkac error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Those 2.4% are peanuts. There would still be a factor of >20 between 20GB of available disk space and 945MB of writable data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`du /dev/sdb` should say **0** if `/dev/sdb` is a block device. Try also `blockdev --report /dev/sdb`.

What happened is that **in the begining you didn't have a device file named `/dev/sdb` at all**, and you created a *regular* file named `/dev/sdb`,
copied 945 MiB into it. This filled the partition on which `/dev/` is located, and thus you get the error. `fdisk` just reads the partition table that is contained in the first 945 MiB and thinks it sees a hard disk of 20 GiB.

When you do `cat mylargefile > /dev/sdb`, the *file* `/dev/sdb` is first truncated to size 0, so there is now 945 MiB free space again that `cat` will proceed to fill.

---

To avoid this: make sure that you open a device by its correct name. In C open the device *without* `O_CREAT`.

Comment: Then what about `cat` failing? and how to access the disk practically? Amusing after I cleanup the file /dev/sdb and reboot and see the RAW disk at /dev/sdb and `du` returns `0`

Comment: "what about cat failing" The partition where `/dev` resides had 945 MiB free space. When you `cat >` into it, the file is first truncated to size 0, then 945 MiB is written and you run out of space.